# SharePoint forms authentication (FBA) roles

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication, roles, targeting

Can anybody help me...

Is it possible to target audiences in SharePoint using FBA roles instead of using SharePoint groups?

Or is there an alternative solution available?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a SharePoint group per Role and add the Role to the group. that way the maintenance is minimum and you are still doing it the clean way by using sharepoint groups....

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I've tried adding the FBA roles to a SharePoint Group but it didn't seem to work kash